# DLL not appearing in the "Loaded Modules" section of MSINFO32

Tags: c++, dll, active-directory

I am trying to implement a password filter dll. I had put up its name under,
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
   SYSTEM
      CurrentControlSet
         Control
            Lsa
and also the dll is 64bit. i had copied it to both "**System32**" folder and "**SysWoW64**" folders. But still the dll doesn't appear in the "**Loaded Modules**" section of MSINFO32. And the dll never fires when a user changes his password. How to check whether a dll is registered with LSA??

Comment: [Wrong key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379392%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), for one.

Comment: @HansPassant I had even tried tat !